# ddms bufferoverflowexception while getting Hprof for my android application

Tags: android, ddms

size of heap for my application is around 215MB .using the DDMS  tried to get HPROF file but unable to get the HPRof file its showing in console as BUFFeroverflow.please help me with this,Thanks in advance

Comment: Your heap is 215MB?  Are you sure?  What device is this on.  That's a HUGE heap.

Comment: Sorry simon i cant tell u about it.app leaking lot of memory can u tell solution for above problem